How to get the log line associated with the max value?
I am executing the following query:
topk(5, max by (job) (max_over_time(
   {job="myjob"}
   | regexp "[^,],(?P<count>[^,]*),.*"
   | unwrap count
   [24h]
)))

This returns a job and a number. I am not interested in that number. I want to get the log line that contains the biggest count. How do I do that?
As a workaround I can execute another query over proper time with:
{job="myjob"}
| regexp "[^,],(?P<count>[^,]*),.*"
| count =~ "(values from the first query joined with '|')"

Is there a better way?

I don't think logql can do this on it's own: AFAIK, combination of log queries and metrics queries is not supported. But I probably can do this in Grafana itself: query list desired labels with your topk query, then all logs in a separate query, and then join them. Right now, I can't nail all transformations needed, but I think it should be doable.
